# Posting Binary data in JSON giving Unexpected Token in JSON error using cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

The curl command to try and post a JSON file with binary data

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" -H "Accept: application/json" --data-ascii @filename.json http://localhost:3002/api/xyz -v -s
```

Gives an error 400

```
Unexpected token \u0011 in JSON at position 13
```

[image]

It appears the error is because data in json *content* variable is in binary containing 0x11 which JSON doesn't allow. How to encode it in utf-8 in cURL before sending this.

Here is the file in binary
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Encoding your binary data to base64,